# How to specify the size of rectangular using RotatedRect in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to use `RotatedRect` in OpenCv to create a rotated rectangular. However I found it was strange that I can not specify the size of rectangular correctly.

For example:

```
Mat img;        //img size is 1920x1080
Point2f center(img.size().width/2,img.size().height/2);
Rect r = RotatedRect(center, img.size(), 90).boundingRect();
```

But when I checked the size of `rect r` after rotation, it was 1081x1921.

Even when I specified the size in `RotatedRect` using `Rect r = RotatedRect(center, Size2f(1919,1079), 90).boundingRect();`, it was still 1081x1921.

How can I set the size of that rotated rectangular to be 1080x1920?

Comment: resize it after process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a bug of opencv RotatedRect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869565/is-it-a-bug-of-opencv-rotatedrect)

Comment: how did you check the size of r? function RotatedRect::boundingRect?

Comment: @Micka I checked the output image and the size of `Rect r` when debugging.